# MySQL truncate text with ellipsis

Tags: mysql, text, trim, ellipsis

Suppose I have a MySQL table of one column: "Message". It is of type TEXT.
I now want to query all rows, but the text can be large (not extremely large but large) and I only want to get a summary of them. For example the result can be populated into a list.

Is there a way to trim the text to a specific length (say, 10 characters), and add ellipsis if the text is trimmed?

For example:

```
Message
-----------
12345678901234
1234567890
12345
12345678901
```

Query result:

```
1234567...
1234567890
12345
1234567...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select case when length(message) > 7 
then concat(substring(message, 1, 7), '...')
else message end as adapted_message
from ...
```

to test/confirm:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH('1234567890') > 7 
THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING('1234567890', 1, 7), '...') 
ELSE '1234567890' END AS adapted_message

UNION  

SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH('12345') > 7 
THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING('12345', 1, 7), '...') 
ELSE '12345' END AS adapted_message
```

Comment: You may want to use `char_length()` instead of `length()` to ensure the truncation occurs at the same amount of characters... `length()` returns the string length in bytes and `char_length()` returns the length in characters.

Comment: There is a VERY common but rather annoying mistake in  this answer. It should be `when length(message) > 10`. Otherwise the produced 'truncated' text might be LONGER than the original text.

I see this all the time in all applications, even Facebook. Don't you hate it that you have to click "more" just to see two letters? "More" has 4!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple one line solution:

```
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(message) > 10, CONCAT(LEFT(message, 7),"..."), message)
```

Answer (score 7):

or...

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(message, 7), IF(LENGTH(message)>7, "…", ""))
FROM table
```

Comment: Great answer! You may want to replace the ellipsis character with three periods though, as not all character encodings will support that character.

Comment: This is a good approach, but works incorrectly when the field is between 7 and 10 characters long.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a new `ELLIPSIS` function in order to make your query readable:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION ELLIPSIS ( str TEXT, max_length INT )
RETURNS TEXT

BEGIN
   DECLARE str_out TEXT;

   IF LENGTH(str) <= max_length THEN
      SET str_out = str;
      
   ELSE
      SET str_out = CONCAT(SUBSTR(str, 1, max_length-3), '...');

   END IF;
   
   RETURN str_out;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you simply do:

```
SELECT ELLIPSIS(Message, 10);
```

Comment: Best solution to my eyes. If I can suggest (what I think to be) an inprovement: I would change the shortened string to 

SET str_out = CONCAT(LEFT(str, max_length-3), '...');

The resulting string will not be longer than the "max_length"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MySQL string functions, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr). You should be able to use some combination of `substring` and `concat` to achieve your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

- Let x be the maximum number of characters to display (therefore x + 3 dots will be the longest string displayed)
- You always want LEFT(field,x)
- If LENGTH(field) > x + 3, append 3 dots
- Otherwise if LENGTH(field) > x, append the remainder of field

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    LEFT(field,x),
    IF(LENGTH(field) > x+3,
       '...',
        IF(LENGTH(field) > x,
            MID(field,x+1,LENGTH(field)),
            ''
        )
    )
) FROM table
```