# Mysql substring string and attach chars such as ... to result command

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

My `subject` field is (maybe) bigger than 100 characters. I want to use LENGTH if subject length is bigger that 100 char in below mysql command and attach `...` to end of SUBSTR `subject`.

```
SELECT id ,
     IF LENGTH(`subject`) <=100 then SUBSTR( `subject`, 1, 100 ) AS subject
     ELSE `subject`
     END IF
FROM `contents`
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [MySQL truncate text with ellipsis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384102/mysql-truncate-text-with-ellipsis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in MySQL.

```
SELECT id ,
     CASE WHEN LENGTH(`subject`) >=100 then CONCAT(SUBSTR( `subject`, 1, 100 ),'...')
     ELSE `subject`
     END AS `subject`
FROM `contents`
```

**[Sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5649c/10)**

Have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) as well.

Comment: i get this error:`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LENGTH(`subject`) <=100 then CONCAT(SUBSTR( `subject`, 1, 100 ),'...') AS subjec' at line 2`

Comment: thanks i get this error `error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LENGTH(subject) <=100 then CONCAT(SUBSTR( subject, 1, 100 ),'...') AS subjec at line 2`

Answer (score 0):

Rather another simpler way could be you can fetch the subject using your simple mysql query. and can display your subject this way!!

For ex: $subject = substr($data['subject'], 1, 100)